# Visual Studio 2010 and IIS Express lock up on build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I have about four web projects that I am hosting in IIS Express. Whenever I do a build in Visual Studio 2010, the build will be blocked until I manually kill IIS Express. The build then completes. A new instance of IIS Express is created that works as expected.

I tried to do a prebuild event to kill IIS Express with taskkill, but the lock up seems to happen before the prebuild event is executed :/

If I stop the hosted sites, Visual Studio 2010 will also build as normal.

From research, one possibility is IIS Express is trying to display a dialog that Visual Studio 2010 is waiting for the user to interact with, but doesn't actually display the dialog.

Has anyone else had an issue with IIS Express and Visual Studio 2010 locking up on building? Or some insight on how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i remember correct the last service pack for vs 2010 corrected that error (at least on my maschine).

Comment: I did install the windows 7 sp 1 and it might of fixed the issue.

Comment: SP1 did not fix it on my side

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like visual studio is trying to do something on port 80, which IIS is blocking ( thats the default listener port for it ).

A simple google search of [port 80 visual studio](http://www.google.co.za/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=port%2080%20visual%20studio) brings up several promising hits ( how to configure it, and hey! 2nd one even has a fix for a similar problem. )

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me constantly, but then again I'm using WinXP / VS2010 / IIS Express 7.5.  I suspect the WinXP part is the culprit, perhaps a bug for this particular scenario?  At any rate, VS2010 wants to rebuild one of my web apps, but *appears* to wait indefinitely on some files in the Temporary ASP.net directory for the web app, until I stop IIS Express.